# Hot to get exit code of wget ftp

Tags: linux

I need to get exit code of ftp execution. My command line is:

```
wget -N ftp://server:pass@server/path/
```

Using:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
```

will check wget execution.

Comment: What is your question?  This looks merely like a statement of trivial fact (and an antipattern at that -- shell scripts should rarely need to examine `$?` explicitly, especially in an `if` statement, which implicitly examines this variable anyway).

Comment: mhmh.. I only need to check if execution of the command wget ftp.. will results ok or if there're some problem like an error of passwork or other.

Comment: Is [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Exit-Status) not helping here?

Answer (score 1):

not tested:

```
wget [wget options] 2>&1 | grep -i "failed\|error"
```